# Angular2 - Focus on input after modal load

Tags: angular

I built a component in Angular 2, and I'm trying to set the focus on the specific input **after** a modal is loaded.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
@Component({
selector: 'login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  showModal: boolean = false;
  @ViewChild('username1') el: ElementRef;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private modalService: ModalService {
    this.modalService.LoginModal.subscribe((show) => {
        this.showModal = show;

        if (show) {
            $('#modal_login_root').modal();
            this.el.nativeElement.focus();
        }
        else {
            $('#modal_login_root').modal('hide');
        }
    });
}
```

And my input is:

```
<input #username1 type="email" class="form-control email active" name="username"
 placeholder="{{ 'Login_EmailField' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="username" />
```

And it's not working :(

Comment: Here is example of using ElementRef https://stackoverflow.com/a/40537428/924646

Comment: I would recommend using ng2-bootstrap for your modals: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't trigger any function until unless DOM rendered , wait till the your modal rendered and then trigger focus , if your using Jquery , then use jquery focus function..

so now you component look like this

```
@Component({
selector: 'login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  showModal: boolean = false; 

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private modalService: ModalService {
    this.modalService.LoginModal.subscribe((show) => {
        this.showModal = show;

        if (show) {
            $('#modal_login_root').modal();
          setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('#username').focus();
           },1000)
        }
        else {
            $('#modal_login_root').modal('hide');
        }
    });
}
```

and your HTML look like this

```
    <input #username1 type="email"  id="username"
    class="form-control email active" name="username"
         placeholder="{{ 'Login_EmailField' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="username" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add auto focus with input field

```
<input type="text" autofocus/>
```

Comment: Its not working. it works for a second and then the focus is disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using **cdkTrapFocus** and **cdkFocusInitial** to specify which element will have **initial focus**. for example:

**In input element add cdkFocusInitial**:

```
    <input
          matInput
          type="text"
          name="username"
          [(ngModel)]="username"
          cdkFocusInitial
    />
```

**In container element add cdkTrapFocus, for example if div is the container element:**

```
     <div class="login-container" cdkTrapFocus>
```