# Why the HTMLDialogElement in Angular doesn't have showModal() method?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When I am writing this, the MDN shows that `HTMLDialogElement` is supported in all browser except Internet Explorer.
But weirdly enough, while using it, there is a warning which says it's not supported in most of the browsers and marks it depreceted. That was not the problem, until I found that calling `showModal()` is giving me error:

*Property 'showModal' does not exist on type `HTMLDialogElement`*

Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
let elem: HTMLDialogElement = document.getElementById("dlg") as HTMLDialogElement;
elem.showModal(); // this line gives error
```

Comment: According to the type definitions for `HTMLDialogElement` there is no method `showModal()`. You could cast `elem` to `any` to make the TypeScript Transpiler accept it: `(elem as any).showModal()`. However, you should not use deprecated APIs ;) If you are using Material with Angular you could use the `MatDialog` service instead.

Comment: Also these types doesn't come from Angular. They are defined by [typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts).

Comment: @majusebetter, thanks. that worked !! You can put it in the answer box for me to mark it as accepted answer

Comment: you shouldn't use `document` while using Angular, use `ElementRef` or 'Render2', Angular should be the only interacting with the DOM

Comment: @Andres2142 just followed this to avoid the ceremony: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46516373/4648930

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the type definitions ([lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts)) for `HTMLDialogElement` there is no method `showModal()`. You could cast `elem` to `any` to make the TypeScript Transpiler accept it:

```
(elem as any).showModal()
```

However, you should not use deprecated APIs. If you are using Material with Angular you could use the `MatDialog` service instead.

Answer (score 4):

`HTMLDialogElement.showModal` is available as of TypeScript 4.8.3.

Run `npm install --save-dev typescript@4.8.3`.